# How to get node url of selected language?

Tags: 8, entities, routes

I have a node with an array of multiple languages.

```
 [19] => Drupal\node\Entity\Node Object
        (
            [in_preview] => 
            [values:protected] => Array
                (
                    [vid] => Array
                        (
                            [x-default] => 19
                        )

                    [langcode] => Array
                        (
                            [x-default] => en
                            [ca] => ca
                        )
```

I'm getting its url as:

```
$options = array('absolute' => TRUE);
$link = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => $key], $options);
```

`print($link)` is giving me `http://test-d8.local/en/node/19` where as I want url of "`ca`" language not "`en`" language. i.e. `http://test-d8.local/ca/node/19`

Is there any way that gives node translations of particular langcode?

This line `$language = $entity->get('langcode')->value;` is giving me the value of chosen language from select list.

Answer (score 6):

You want to use toUrl() with the language option.

```
$node->toUrl('canonical', ['language' => $node->language()]);
```

Unfortunately, toUrl() currently doesn't automatically respect the active language.

Comment: `$node->toUrl('canonical', ['language' => $node->language()];` is not working. I added `$node->toUrl('canonical', ['language' => $node->language()]->toString();` Now its giving `/en/node/19` not even absolute url.

Comment: To make it absolute you can use the setAbsolute method `$url->setAbsolute(TRUE)`

Answer (score 3):

```
$language = 'ca';
$link = $value->getTranslation($language)->url();
$title =  $value->getTranslation($language)->title->value;
```

this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the translation of the node like this:

```
$node = $node->getTranslation('ca');
```

And, depending what you need, you can get the link or url like this:

```
$link = $node->toLink();
$url = $node->toUrl();
```

Comment: Doesn't actually work like that AFAIK, see my answer.

Comment: I have tried this, but `$node = $value->getTranslation('ca');
       $link = $node->toUrl();
       print_r($link);die;` is giving a 404 infinite loop.