# Create link to node in specific language

Tags: nodes, i18n-l10n

So I need to create links to specific translations of a node but am having issues.

This is my code:

```
foreach($entities as $entity) {
$urls[] = Url::fromRoute('entity.node.canonical', [
        'node' => $entity->id(),
        'language' => $entity->language()->getId(),
      ]);
}
```

`$entity` in this context is `EntityInterface`.

But this gives me `/node/1185?language=es` instead of `/es/node/1185`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get node url of selected language?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/204755/how-to-get-node-url-of-selected-language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$entity->toUrl('canonical', ['language' => $entity->language()]);

Taken from this [question thread](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/204755/how-to-get-node-url-of-selected-language)